# How to find sum of all values divisible by 3 in the list using while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to find sum of all values divisible by 3 in the num_list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18] using while loop.

I'm trying to get 51. I tried something to get 51 but i don't get it.

```
total = 0
 
list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18]

while list % 3 == 0:
    total += list
    print (total)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = 0
nums = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18]
for num in nums:
    if num % 3 == 0:
        total += num
print(total)
```

But since you need to use a while loop:

```
total = 0
nums = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18]
index = 0
while index < len(nums):
    num = nums[index]
    if num % 3 == 0:
        total += num
    index = index + 1
print(total)
```

Comment: It is recommended not to use the names of built-in functions or classes as variable names - so you should avoid `list`.

Comment: @Kenny it's still giving error

Comment: @forzakot Yes, I forgot to increment the `index`. That's why a for loop fits better in this place

Comment: @Kenny thank you so much. I've been trying to figure it out for 1 hour

Answer (score 1):

Optimize way

```
nums = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18]
total = sum(num for num in nums if num % 3 == 0)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
 
list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18]

for i in list:
    if i % 3 == 0:
        total += i
print(total)
```

you would have to iterate through the list using a for loop as this is the easiest way.

Comment: This is the same answer as the one given earlier ...